# Mostrar imágenes externas tomadas por URL en reporting services

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, reporting

Necesito mostrar imágenes externas tomadas por URL en reporting services, cuando se programa y hace el preview se visualiza correctamente pero cuando esta en producción no, y al exportar el reporte  a pdf aparece una x donde debería aparecer la imagen.

De acuerdo a lo que he investigado active la cuenta desatendida de ejecución pero al querer cargar el reporte aparece como si el servicio estuviera caído aunque en la configuración de la misma se reinicia correctamente.

Me pueden asesorar a que puede deberse esto, por favor?

Comment: No es raro que un servidor productivo este restringido para acceder -usar y redistribuir- contenido externo de fuentes no-confiables.

Comment: Gracias por la observación. Efectivamente fue una situación causada por permisos